# Rails has_one vs has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many, has-one

I've a model say `Book` and another model named say `Title`. The associations are simply defined below.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :title
end

class Title < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :book
end
```

Now, if I generate a schema with a foreign key of `book_id` in `Title` and create a new record for `Book`, I am not being able to create a new `Title`  record via `book.title.create!` as `book.title` returns `nil`.

But, if I change the association to

```
 class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :titles
 end
```

then I am clearly able to create a new `Title` record using `book.title.create!`. So, what I have to do to make it work with the `has_one` association is do something like `book.title = Title.create!(foo: "bar", book_id: book.id)`.

When I checked the values for `book.title` in the latter case, the console returns `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` but for the former, `book.title` returns `nil` and hence the `NoMethod Error for nil class`.

I tried following the official docs and some other posts in stack regarding this. But somehow, its still unclear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of this behaviour is that `Rails` creates 
methods in a form of `create_#{association_name}` for every `has_one association_name`. There are [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) for this, if you need extra information.

Thus, to create a `title` for a `book`, you'll need something like:

```
book.create_title
```

It will perform the trick, you're expecting

Comment: is this the actual behaviour of rails?

Comment: Additional documentation worth reading is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html